# Why does this String.Format operation throw FormatException?

Tags: c#, .net

I created a workaround for it, but was perplexed that the following string:

```
string dpicker = "<script>$(function() { $(\"#{0}\").datepicker();});</script>";
```

throws FormatException when performing this:

```
String.Format(dpicker, "DatePicker");
```

What is the actual problem?

Comment: I think you have to escape the curly braces in format strings, by placing two of them.

Comment: Thanks, @Zack, but you really ought to have put that in as an Answer.  I can't give you rep points for comments, and now it's too late!

Comment: I just typed it out quick as a comment, then went to see what the problem was in Visual Studio, and by the time I got back, there were already 2 answers! I didn't want to give you an answer, if I didn't make sure it worked first.

Comment: Well, @Zack, that's happened to me before, too, so I know the story.  Thanks for your assistance anyway!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to escape the curly-braces for the function:

```
string dpicker = "<script>$(function() {{ $(\"#{0}\").datepicker();}});</script>";
//                                     ^^                          ^^
```

As used here, the correct way to do that is to double them up. See [Escaping Braces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd(v=vs.110).aspx).

The `string.Format` method works by looking through the entire string, character-by-character, and choosing whether they fall into the "literal" category, or the one for format arguments. As soon as it saw your unescaped curly-brace, it understood that to mean "we're formatting now," so it first looked for a numeric character (of course, that's not the only acceptable value there in the curly braces, but at least one digit must come first), couldn't find one, and threw the exception.

Answer (score 4):

`String.Format` was trying to interpret that first `{` as the start of a placeholder, and of course couldn't parse `$(\"#{0}\").datepicker();` into some kind of numerical value. You can escape brackets in a format string by doing `{{` and `}}`. So this code should work:

```
string dpicker = "<script>$(function() {{ $(\"#{0}\").datepicker();}});</script>";
var s = String.Format(dpicker, "DatePicker");
```

Comment: Error: Unrecognized escape sequence.

Comment: `\}` and `\{` are unrecognized excape sequences.  This will not compile.

Answer (score 2):

The extra curly braces, escape them using double curly braces `{{` and `}}`:

```
string dpicker = "<script>$(function() {{ $(\"#{0}\").datepicker();}});</script>";
```